# Animation complete not called JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, animation, dom

I am trying to animate an image with a completion function. 
The animation works fine but the complete property is not called. 
I tried looking around and didn't find any result on the matter that says that what i'm doing is wrong. 
I tried on `Chrome` and `Firefox` 
 I am using the code below

```
document.getElementById("myImageId").animate([{
      transform: 'translateY(0px)'
   },
   {
      transform: 'translateY(-300px)'
   }
], {
   duration: 300,
   complete: function () {
      alert('end ani')
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Element.animate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) returns a [`Animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation) object, and you can attach an event handler for `finish` to the object:

```js
var animation = document.querySelector('#myImageId').animate([{
    transform: 'translateY(0px)'
  },
  {
    transform: 'translateY(-300px)'
  }
], {
  duration: 300,
  delay: 300,
  fill: 'forwards',
});

animation.addEventListener('finish', () => alert('end ani'));
```

```html
<div id="myImageId"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
```

Another option, which is only supported by FireFox currently, is the [`Animation.finished`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/finished) promise:

```js
var animation = document.querySelector('#myImageId').animate([{
    transform: 'translateY(0px)'
  },
  {
    transform: 'translateY(-300px)'
  }
], {
  duration: 300,
  delay: 300,
  fill: 'forwards',
});

animation.finished.then(() => alert('end ani'));
```

```html
<div id="myImageId"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
```